# Visual Force page converted to Lightning still appears with Classic feel

Tags: visualforce, lightning-experience, migration

Has anyone experienced this? I've already converted some Visual Force Pages to Lightning Experience thru enabling them in settings and adding lightningStylesheets="true", it already appears to Lightning Experience with the lightning feels but it just suddenly turns back to classic feels and after some time it just reverts back to lightning feels. I'm not sure if what I did with my code that may have triggered it. I hope to hear some feedback from those who have experienced this. I'd highly appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: by any chance are you opening classic and lightning in two different tabs in same browser?

Comment: I'm still trying to observe that one because there are instances that I'm opening two consoles, one in lightning and the other one in classic which are in the same environment. That's my conclusion too right now. The solution that I've come up so far is by closing all the tabs from the same environment and when I opened it in lightning, it's already back to it's lightning version of feel or style.

Comment: I can definitely tell you opening classic and lightning at the same time is the reason behind your observation.

Comment: Yes indeed it is. Thanks sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open the VF page with lightningStylesheets = *True* from a classic user i.e when you are viewing salesforce in classic globally, it shows in classic feel.

And when you view the VF page as Lightning User i.e., when salesforce is viewed in Lightning globally, it shows in lightning feel.

I've observed the above behavior in my experience.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience. Yes, I think there are instances like that whenever I open the VF pages. I'll try to implement that in my environment and I'll try to get back at you.